# How could I resolve the following configuration on airport express?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, airport-express

I've tried to configure my airport express in order to make a private network and also get access to internet, the thing is my linksys just has broken and all I have is the airport express, I've managed my DHCP to provide IP directions, but the internet connection is not working, is it something with the NAT?? or how can I access internet with my configuration, if the airport is reset to factory settings everything works fine, so, what is the problem??

My computer is going to be DHCP and DNS server

Comment: Can you elaborate?   What do you mean by private network?

Comment: Could you post your current settings in the airport configuration utility? The NAT feature is tied with DHCP, so you cannot use your own computer as DHCP.